# Count query with PHP Elastica and Symfony2 FosElasticaBundle

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

I'm on a Symfony 2.5.6 project using FosElasticaBundle (@dev).

In my project, i just need to get the total hits count of a request on Elastic Search. That is, i'm querying Elastic Search with a normal request, **but through the special "count" URL**:

```
localhost:9200/_search?search_type=count
```

*Note the "search_type=count" URL param.*

Here's the example query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": []
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "media.category.id": [
                  681
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "published_at": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  },
  "size": 1
}
```

The results contains a normal JSON response but **without any documents in the `hits` part**. From this response i easily get the total count:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 81,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": [ ]
    }
}
```

Okay, `hits.total == 81`.

Now, **i couldn't find any solution to do the same through FOSElasticaBundle, from a repository.**

I tried this:

```
$query = (...) // building the Elastica query here
$count = $this->finder->findPaginated(
    $query,
    array(ES::OPTION_SEARCH_TYPE => ES::OPTION_SEARCH_TYPE_COUNT)
)->getNbResults();
```

But i get an Attempted to load class "Pagerfanta". I don't want Pagerfanta.

Then this:

```
$count = $this->finder->createPaginatorAdapter(
    $query,
    array(ES::OPTION_SEARCH_TYPE => ES::OPTION_SEARCH_TYPE_COUNT)
)->getTotalHits();
```

But it would always give me 0.

Would be easy if i had access to the Elastica Finder service from the repository (i could then get a ResultSet from the query search, and this ResultSet has a correct getTotalHits() method). But services from repository... you know.

Thank you for any help or clue!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same challenge, getting access to the searchable interface from inside the repo. Here's what I ended up with:

Create `AcmeBundle\Elastica\ExtendedTransformedFinder`. This just extends the `TransformedFinder` class and makes the `searchable` interface accessible.

```php
<?php

namespace AcmeBundle\Elastica;

use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder;

class ExtendedTransformedFinder extends TransformedFinder
{

    /**
     * @return \Elastica\SearchableInterface
     */
    public function getSearch()
    {
        return $this->searchable;
    }

}
```

Make the bundle use our new class; in `service.yml`:

```yaml
parameters:
      fos_elastica.finder.class: AcmeBundle\Elastica\ExtendedTransformedFinder
```

Then in a repo use the `getSearch` method of our class and do what you want :)

```php
class SomeSearchRepository extends Repository
{
    public function search(/* ... */)
    {
        // create and set your query as you like
        $query = Query::create();

        // ...

        // then run a count query
        $count = $this->finder->getSearch()->count($query);

    }
}
```

**Heads up** this works for me with version 3.1.x. Should work starting with 3.0.x.

Comment: Confirm, works nicely with current 3.1.x-dev. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, here we go: it is *not possible*.

You cannot, as of version 3.1.x-dev (2d8903a), get the total matching document count returned by elastic search from FOSElasticaBundle, because this bundle does not expose this value.

The `RawPaginatorAdapter::getTotalHits()` method contains this code:

```
return $this->query->hasParam('size')
    ? min($this->totalHits, (integer) $this->query->getParam('size'))
    : $this->totalHits;
```

which prevents to get the correct `$this->totalHits` without actually requiring any document. Indeed, if you set size to 0, to tell elasticsearch not to return any document, only meta information, `RawPaginatorAdapter::getTotalHits()` will return 0.

So FosElasticaBundle doesn't provide a way to know this total hits count, you could only do that through the Elastica library directly. Of course with the downisde that Elastica finders are natively available in `\FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository`. You'd had to make a new service, do some injection, and inovke your service instead of the FOSElasticaBundle one for repositories... ouch.

I chose another path, i forked https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle and changed the method code as follow:

```
/**
 * Returns the number of results.
 *
 * @param boolean $genuineTotal make the function return the `hits.total`
 * value of the search result in all cases, instead of limiting it to the
 * `size` request parameter.
 * @return integer The number of results.
 */
public function getTotalHits($genuineTotal = false)
{
    if ( ! isset($this->totalHits)) {
        $this->totalHits = $this->searchable->search($this->query)->getTotalHits();
    }

return $this->query->hasParam('size') && !$genuineTotal
    ? min($this->totalHits, (integer) $this->query->getParam('size'))
    : $this->totalHits;
}
```

`$genuineTotal` boolean restores the elasticsearch behaviour, without introducing any BC break. I could also have named it `$ignoreSize` and use it the opposite way.

I opened a Pull Request: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/pull/748

We'll see! If that could help just one person i'd be happy already!

Comment: How I can use this on `3.2.2` version?

Answer (score 1):

While, you can get the index instance as a service (fos_elastica.index.INDEX_NAME.TYPE_NAME) and ask for count() method.

Joan